Allocating memory dynamically for each thread CUDA
I need to allocate an array for each thread, but the length of the array is known only at runtime. Once the array length is calculated, it is a constant value. cudaMalloc does not seem to work inside the kernel.
Is there anyway I can do it? Something like this -
__constant__ int length;

__global__ void foo() {

int a[length];

}
int main() {

//do some length calculations here.
//copy the calculated value to length.

foo<<<Blocks, Threads>>>();

}

Edit - I tried the following code but I got no output. Why is that?
__global__ void sample() {

    int* a;
    cudaMalloc(&a, sizeof(int) * 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
}
int main() {

    sample << <1, 1>> > ();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

Edit 2 - Does templating work for constant variables? I tried this code but it gave an error -
__constant__ int length = 4;

template<int size>
__global__ void sample() {

printf("%d", size);
}
int main() {

    sample<length> << <1, 1>> > ();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

expression must have constant value.

Sorry if I am asking dumb questions. I am new to CUDA.

cudaMalloc certainly works inside kernels, but you must pre-size the runtime heap correctly so you don’t run out of space. But I am highly sceptical that you really need dynamic memory allocation for this. For a manageable range of length values, templating seems much more sensible

Dynamic Global Memory Allocation and Operations

For cudaMalloc() in device code nvcc needs -rdc=true. See here. I recommend device malloc() instead if you don't use dynamic parallelism (as described in the documentation I linked above). The memory is the same.

If length is a constant as in your sample code, then the length must be known before the kernel starts, right? Then why can't you allocate a 2D array with one entry per thread before launching the kernel? Preferably combine it with a grid-strided loop to use the minimum number threads that are optimal for your GPU

Or if you want __local__ memory, you can use the alloca function

@talonmies how can I use templating here?

You template the kernel on length, instantiate all lengths that you could need an then dispatch to the right instantiation at runtime (via conditionals or switch statement for example). Then you can use int a[length]

__constant__ just means read-only memory. For templates you need constexpr, i.e. values known at compile time. But you wrote that the lenght is only available at runtime, so you need to instantiate all possible values of length.

See this switch statement for an example of the technique (although it isn't used for a static array here).

Here you go: https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/Gxfoaf51h

See In a CUDA kernel, how do I store an array in "local thread memory"? for performance considerations.

Allocating memory on the GPU (aka device) works pretty much the same as it does on the CPU (aka host).
A simple malloc will do, CUDA is designed to be as much alike to normal C++ code as possible.
If you know the length beforehand, then you're only going to allocate it once. So it's likely that the allocation is not time critical, meaning there is no need for template tricks.
Memory on the global heap is allocated using malloc.
As documented in section 7.35 of the CUDA programming guide
   template <typename T>
   __device__ T* myalloc(int length) {    
      T* buffer = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * length);
      return buffer;
   }

However note that:

The device memory heap has a fixed size that must be specified before any program using malloc() [...] default [is] eight megabytes

The following API functions get and set the heap size you can allocate on the device using device-side malloc (it does not affect cudaMalloc calls from the host).
__host__ cudaDeviceGetLimit(size_t* size, cudaLimitMallocHeapSize)
__host__ cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, size_t size)

You must ensure you have enough memory available, or your allocations in your kernel will fail.
There is no need to call cudaMalloc on the device, because as per the above programming guide this just maps to malloc anyway.
Some comments mention template tricks, I fail to see how this helps, because it does not scale if you want to use different sizes for different threads.
Small buffers
If your allocation sizes are small and you use only one block (1024 threads max) then its better to use shared memory. Allocate a single buffer big enough to hold all your data and use a lookup to get the start of each thread's data, something like:
template <int totalsize, int threadcount> 
__global__ void test(int* sizes) {
    int LocalBuffer[totalsize]; //very slow!
    __shared__ uint32_t starts[threadcount];
    __shared__ int buffer[totalsize];
    
     const auto Get = [=](const int index) {
         const auto start = starts[threadIdx.x];
         return buffer[start + index];
     }

     const auto Set = [&](cost int index, const int data) {
         const auto start = starts[threadIdx.x];
         buffer[start + index] = data;
     }
}

The LocalBuffer in the above example is mapped to local memory, which is really global memory and very slow if not cached in the tiny L1 cache. Shared memory is much faster, even with the extra address calculation.

If totalsize is not too big and the buffer is only indexed with constant expressions (i.e. loops are unrolled), it goes to registers instead of local memory.

That depends, if the array is incorrectly addressed, it will be moved to local memory. Registers cannot be accessed as an array would, in particular dynamic addressing cannot be done in registers.

That seems like a reformulation of what I wrote?

What I meant to say that local memory is bad, really bad. If L1 cache is oversubscribed, as it often is, it will spill to L2 or even global mem. Therefore you want to avoid putting vars in local mem at all costs. Much much better to put them in shared memory, because then they cannot be spilled. Automatic variables live in registers (good), but automatic array can only live in variables under ideal conditions (as per your argument); my point is that those conditions are rare and should not be relied upon, because the costs of local memory getting spilled to L2 is massive (100's of cycles).

The funny thing is that Nvidia's own CUB algorithms rely on this because they use automatic arrays as input and output. Shared memory can also be the limiting ressource in certain applications and compared to global memory (pre-allocated or via malloc) local memory is no worse. They are different tools for different problems/situations and OP doesn't give enough context to tell which tool will or wont work (the best).
